# Passport with google-outh strategy

Tags: passport.js

I am creating API for login with google & login with facebook
whenever I call API URL I got error :
**"TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a verify callback"**

I am using local server for testing ,
Here is my code to implement google-outh-strategy with node.js

```
      clientID: "clientId",
      clientSecret: "clientsecret",
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:3001/",
     passReqToCallback: true
    },
      function (request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        console.log(refreshToken);
        console.log(accessToken);
        console.log(profile);
        done(null, profile)
      }
    ));

Here is my references Docs for it :
http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-google-oauth2/
```

Comment: Your `callbackURL` looks a little off to me. Usually they are structured something like `http://localhost:3001/oauth/callback`. In the Google Cloud Console (APIs & Services -> Credentials -> OAuth 2.0 Client IDs) did you register your URL as an Authorized redirect URI?

Comment: Yes , In the google cloud console I registered my URL & client ID,&Secret 
Is it compulsory that have to set CallBack URL like this : http://localhost:3001/oauth/callback ???